# Handling network errors with fetch

Tags: javascript, redux

I'm using the [fetch](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/) API with Redux with the thunk middleware and I think the way to handle network errors is kinda strange. This is a simple async action:

```
const fetchData = (id) => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch(requestData())

  return fetch(`/my/api/${ id }`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => dispatch(receiveDataSuccess(json, id)))
    .catch(err => dispatch(receiveDataFail(err, id)))
}
```

But if there's a network error like 404 or 500 status it gets converted to a JSON parsing error like `SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input`. To get around it I changed my action to something like this:

```
const fetchData = (id) => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch(requestData())

  return fetch(`/my/api/${ id }`)
    .then(response => {
      switch (response.status) {
        case 200:
          return response.json()

        default:
          // Here I just throw an error for it
          // to be catched by the promise chain
          throw {
            status: response.status
          }
      }
    })
    .then(json => dispatch(receiveDataSuccess(json, id)))
    .catch(err => dispatch(receiveDataFail(err, id)))
}
```

This way I can show a more meaningful error message to the user than just a *"There was an error"*.

Is it the proper way to handle this or am I missing something?